# Vue for loop for objects not working

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am trying to create a top menu with dropdown buttons when iterating over an object that looks like this:

```
links: {
      store: 'store',
      language: [{'target': '/english'},{'target': '/norwegian'}],
      login: 'user/login'
    }
```

I have tried to achieve that by making a loop that looks like this:

```
       <div v-for="(value, key) in links" :key="key" class="control">
            <div v-if='Array.isArray(value)'>
                <dropdown-menu :menu="value"></dropdown-menu>
            </div>
            <div v-else>
                <a :href="value">
                    {{ key }}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But, I get errors:

> Property or method "value" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data
>   properties in the data option.

Even if I declare the value and key with initial values of null, it is not rendering anything:

```
data() {
  return {
    data: null,
    value: null,
    key: null,
  };
},
```

This is the dropdown menu component:

```
<template>
  <div class="dropdown is-active">
    <div class="dropdown-trigger">
      <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
        <span>Dropdown button</span>
        <span class="icon is-small">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
          Dropdown item
        </a>
        <a class="dropdown-item">
          Other dropdown item
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item is-active">
          Active dropdown item
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
          Other dropdown item
        </a>
        <hr class="dropdown-divider">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
          With a divider
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'dropdown-menu',
    props: ['menu'],
    data() {
      return {};
    },
  };
</script>
```

But, the dropdown menu is not even shown in the vue dev tools when I go to the top-bar component.

**Update**

For some reason if I removed the divs, and changed the template to this:

```
<dropdown-menu v-if='Array.isArray(value)' :menu="link"></dropdown-menu>
<a :href="value" v-else>
     {{ key }}
</a>
```

If somebody could explain it, that would be great.

Comment: As [the documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object) notes it's definitely possible to do what you are trying to do. The error is a little ambiguous because there's nothing to say that it was generated by this piece of Vue template.

Comment: Can you add the code for the `dropdown-menu`?

Comment: I have added dropdown-menu, the problem is it doesn't even show up in the vue dev tools.

Comment: my guess is `Array.isArray` not working as expected, try to extract it to a method and debug it